# can someone suggest a quick oneliner to convert 20111214 to 2011.12.14 in unix?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

i think this should be do-able in sed/awk, right? convert the following list to 2011.08.01 ... etc

```
20110801
20110802
20110803
20110804
20110805
20110808
```

just not smart enough to figure out how to do it

any suggestiongs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using GNU date:

```
    for date in 20110801 20110802 20110803 20110804 20110805 20110808; do
            date -d "$date" +%Y.%m.%d
    done
```

It barfs on invalid date.

Comment: I think this is the neatest solutions here. neverthelless, thanks a lot for the guys below who helped with sed/awk solutions. have a nice holiday!

Answer (score 7):

```
date -d '20111214' +'%Y.%m.%d'
```

The inputstring can be close to everything which can be identified as a date.

Answer (score 3):

```
export V=20111010;echo ${V:0:4}.${V:4:2}.${V:6:2}
```

So for your case, something like:

```
while read x; do echo ${x:0:4}.${x:4:2}.${x:6:2}; done
```

Comment: I suppose, this is bashism. You should probably point out that it would not work with `sh`.

Comment: I just learned a new word again. Bashism sounds like plague :-)

Comment: For POSIX sh, you can do `tail=${V#????}; echo "${V%????}.${tail%??}.${tail#??}"`

Answer (score 3):

In sed:

```
sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1.\2.\3/'
```

As pointed out by potong in a comment, it's not actually necessary to specify all three groups. You could instead use

```
sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)/\1.\2./'
```

Comment: Is the 3rd back reference necessary?

Comment: @potong No, it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
 sed 's/../.&/3g'
```

Answer (score 1):

gawk

```
gawk '/^[0-9]+$/{print substr($0,1,4)"."substr($0,5,2)"."substr($0,7,2)}' input.txt
```

Comment: Using `NF` instead of `/^[0-9]+$/` will make `awk` skip blank lines.

Comment: i think, /^[0-9]+$/ is better than NF == 1.

Answer (score 0):

For awk, why substr when you have printf??

```
awk 'NF{printf("%.4s.%.2d.%.2d\n", $1, $1%10000/100, $1%100)}'
```